# Horizontal Bar with Months of the Year

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a Bar with the months of a year I selected. As an example

```
2015   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   Mai   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
```

The year will be `SELECT OPTION` and every month will be `LINK` which I set the `HREF`

There is something ?

Comment: post some code what u have tried? will help us to solve the issue.. :)

Comment: The think is that I try to find out how this can be implemented or if there is something already by plugin..... if there is no then I will post later a try...

Answer (score 1):

How does this solution strike you?

**Html**

```
<div id="widget">
    <select id="year">
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select> 
    <a id="Jan" href="#">Jan</a>
    <a id="Feb" href="#">Feb</a>
    <a id="Etc" href="#">Etc</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#year').change(function () {
        var year = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://localhost/' + year + '/' + $(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
});
```

[And a fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/z3fk2zfd/)

Comment: Thank you Zac for you answer... I will test it.....